# How to copy the contents of one xml file to another file in Grails?

Tags: file, grails, file-io

I have created one XML file using Grails, now I want to copy the contents of this file to a datacenter. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you need to make the copy of the file, if it is inside your code, i.e. programmatically, you can use [AntBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Ant+from+Groovy) groovy library but if it is something that you can do inside the Grails scripts you can use Ant.copy to copy the file, something like this:

```
Ant.copy(toFile: "${newPathForFile}/newFileName.xml", filtering: true, overwrite: true) {
  fileset(file: "${pathWhereFileIs}/fileName.xml")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [antbuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Ant+from+Groovy) from groovy. Maybe you have to add some libs.